# Passing Array By Reference To Function in C

Tags: c, arrays, xcode, macos

I'm having a real difficult time getting this code to work. I'm trying to pass an array by reference to a function, in order to modify it in that function. Then I need the modifications to be handed back to the original caller function.

I have searched here for a similar problem, but couldn't find anything that can run successfully like the way I want to do it.

Here's my code, I would really appreciate any help. Thanks a lot:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE_OF_VALUES 5
#define SIZE_OF_STRING 100

void set_values(char **values);

void set_values(char **values)
{
    *values = malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE_OF_VALUES);
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(char)*SIZE_OF_VALUES); i++) {
        values[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE_OF_STRING);
        values[i] = "Hello";
        //puts(values[i]); //It works fine here.
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *values;
    set_values(&values);

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(char)*SIZE_OF_VALUES); i++) {
        puts(values[i]); //It does not work!
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are trying to create an array of arrays, so "values" should be a pointer to pointer (char **value).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've changed to (char **values) and removed the (&) reference, the code still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You should have three-level pointers - `void set_values(char ***values)`, read it as a "a reference (first `*`) to an array (second `*`) of `char*` (third `*`)"
2. Each element in `*values` should be a pointer (`char*`) not `char`, so you need:

   ```
   *values = malloc(sizeof(char*)*SIZE_OF_VALUES);
   ```
3. You are leaking memory, first mallocing then assigning literal, and additionally not dereferencing `values`, you need either:

   ```
   (*values)[i] = "Hello";
   ```

   or

   ```
   (*values)[i] = strdup("Hello");  // you will have to free it later
   ```

   or

   ```
   (*values)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE_OF_STRING); // you will have to free this as well
   strcpy((*values)[i], "Hello");
   ```
4. In your `main`, you should declare `char **values;` as it is a pointer to an array of `char*` (character string/array).
5. In you loop you are incorrectly multiplying indices by `sizeof`, index is counted in elements not in bytes. Thus, you need:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_VALUES; i++)
   ```
6. Don't forget to free the memory at the end.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for the fast reply and the excellent explanation of the problem. I accepted your answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `char ***` type for your parameter of  your `set_values` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE_OF_VALUES 5

void set_values(char ***values)
{
    *values = malloc(sizeof (char *) * SIZE_OF_VALUES);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_VALUES; i++) {
        (*values)[i] = "Hello";
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char **values;
    set_values(&values);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_VALUES; i++) {
        puts(values[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course you have to check for `malloc` return value and `free` allocated memory before exit of main.

Answer (score 0):

`char *` is a one dimensional array of char. but you want your code in `set_values` sets values to a two dimensional array.
In order to make this work, define:

values as `char **values;`

set_values as `void set_values(char ***values)`

allocate the pointers for the char arrays as:
`*values = malloc(sizeof(char*)*SIZE_OF_VALUES);`

Besides that your loop is a bit strange:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(char)*SIZE_OF_VALUES); i++) {
```

should be replaced with

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_VALUES; i++) {
```

and finally, if you want to copy a string into your now allocated array use

```
strncpy((*values)[i], "Hello",  SIZE_OF_STRING-1);
(*values)[i][SIZE_OF_STRING-1] = '\0';
```

so in total:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define SIZE_OF_VALUES 5
#define SIZE_OF_STRING 100

void set_values(char ***values);

void set_values(char ***values)
{
    const char * content = "Hello";
    *values = malloc(sizeof(char*)*SIZE_OF_VALUES);
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_VALUES; i++) {
        (*values)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE_OF_STRING);
        strncpy((*values)[i], content, SIZE_OF_STRING-1);
        (*values)[i][SIZE_OF_STRING-1] = '\0';
        if(strlen(content) >= SIZE_OF_STRING){
            fprintf(stderr,"Warning content string did not fit into buffer!\n");
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char **values;
    set_values(&values);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_VALUES; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", values[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_VALUES; i++) {
       free(values[i]);
    }
    free(values);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
void set_values(char ***values)
{
    int i;
    char ** val;

    val = *values = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*SIZE_OF_VALUES);
    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(char)*SIZE_OF_VALUES); i++) 
        val[i] = "Hello";
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char **values;
    int i;
    set_values(&values);

    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(char)*SIZE_OF_VALUES); i++) 
        puts(values[i]); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just posting the fixed code teaches OP nothing. For me, this is a worthless answer.

Answer (score -3):

You have an extra `*` in this line:

```
*values = malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE_OF_VALUES);
```

Which should be:

```
values = malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE_OF_VALUES);
```

Also you have considerable problem in your main, `char* values` should be `char** values`, passing your `char* values` by reference (`set_values(&values);`) may cause segmentation fault I suspect.

For affecting the outer array, it's already being affected because when passing to the function you are only copying a pointer that points to the same place, so the modifications will affect the same memory blocks.

Comment: Passing by reference is only supported in C++. As the question is tagged as "C", he would need three level of pointers there.